# Practical nozzle question / mass of finger?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

A spray bottle i own broke off its compressor tip so i fashioned another one from a rubber tube, a pen lid, an ear plug and a 1 mm radius tube from a computer cleaning duster.

The opening of the spray is covered by the rubber tube completely. The ear plug has a hole in the center and put inside the pen lid. The cleaning duster tube is inserted through the pen lid hole, through the ear plug to the opening of the spray. This system is completely confined inside the rubber tube, and the only possible leakage comes from the pen tip which does not fully enclose the cleaning duster tube.

[image]

Having done this, calculations for velocity had to be made!

Subscript $_w$=water. Setting up work relation for pump.

$W_{pump}=E=m_wgh+\frac{1}{2}m_wv^2$

The rubber tube is filled above the center of action, no potential energy is needed.

$h=0$

$W_{pump}=\frac{1}{2}mv_w^2$

Using relations..

$m=\rho V$

$W=\frac{1}{2}\rho _w V v_w^2 $

Using more relations..

$W=Fd=PAd$

$V=Ad$

$v_{fluid}=v=\sqrt{\frac{2W}{\rho V}}=\sqrt{\frac{2P}{\rho}}$

Using even more relations..

$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{m}{A}\frac{dv_{ext}}{dt}$

$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{v_{ext}-v_i}{t-t_i}=\frac{v_{ext}}{t}$, since $v_i=0,t_i=0$

Calculating the work done from the trigger $m_{fin}$ is mass of the "finger?"

$W_\theta=F \theta = \frac{1}{2}m_{fin}{v^2_{\theta}}$

Since by trigger design $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$, assume max $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Also, by design $v_{ext}=\frac{\theta}{t}$

$v_{\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{2F \theta}{m_{fin}}}=\sqrt{2a \theta}=\sqrt{\frac{2\theta v_{ext}}{t}}=\sqrt{2} \frac{\theta}{t}$

Going back to the velocity of fluid

$v_{fluid}=\sqrt{\frac{2P}{\rho}}=\sqrt{\frac{2m_{fin}v_{\theta}}{\rho A t}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{8} m_{fin} \theta}{\rho A t^2}}$

Using known values..

$\frac{1}{3} \leq t(s) \leq {1}$ , assume max $t=\frac{1}{3} [s]$

$A=\pi r^2 = \pi 10^{-6} [m^2]$

Approximating $\rho = 10^3 [\frac{kg}{m^3}] $

Gives the final expression

$v_{fluid} = c \sqrt{m_{fin}}$, where $c=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{8} \theta}{\rho A t^2}}=92.12$

For approximate $v_{fluid} = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{m}{s}]$, i get $m_{fin}=30 [mg]$

My question is, what is $m_{fin}$ in this case? I can't believe it's the actual mass of my finger, it seems too little for a finger to weigh 30 mg. Is it some kind of theoretical quantity like an average distribution? I know the 1st $v_{fluid}$ formula is correct, as for the last one, it seems strange.